# How capture tag <a>

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I need to capture all tag  in a page with jquery. The page is formed by

```
<a>A</a>
<a>B</a>
```

How can I capture this tag? I'm tring with this code :

```
$(":a").each(function( index ) {

         });
```

but it doesn't work and it gives me this exception:

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: a
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: use element selector `$("a")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, with `:` you're selecting pseudo elements. Try this

```
$("a").each(function( index ) {

});
```

Have a look at [css selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).